# Meta_query and numeric comparison

Tags: custom-field, wp-query

I have a WP_Query with meta_query filter on meta_value.

```
if( ($capacity != '') && ($capacity > 0) ) $filters[] = array('key' => 'mb_capacity','compare' => '>','value' => $capacity, 'type' => 'NUMERIC');
and then later i set the  'meta_query' => $filters of the query
```

The custom field mb_capacity represents an number but WP store it as a String.
I was thinking the "type=>'numeric'" option will handle that, but unfortunatly it doesn't work, the comparison still be done on String instead of Integer.

Is there any solution to that problem ?

Note that i'm using WP 3.2.1.

Many thanks for any suggestions

Comment: Can you provide some more information? Which values are you having problems with? The code you showed should work as far as I see. The `'type' => 'NUMERIC'` part causes the meta_value to be cast to a number in SQL: `CAST(wp_postmeta.meta_value AS SIGNED)`, before being compared.

Comment: Idiotic to close this